# Accessing global variables in a flash[:notice]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is deals_controller.rb. And it works like this, except two things.

1. Not sure how to call Deal.count to add in my flash[:notice] . I get the hunch that its not calling something global.
2. I need that contional statement back, as I'm pretty sure its responsible for actually adding the new @deal . So I assume my syntax is off. Do note, I added an extra 'end' when I uncomment this block.

   def create

   -# This will use the disclaimer_ids submitted from the check boxes in the view

   -# to add/delete deal.disclaimers entries to matched the list of checked boxes.

   @deal = Deal.new(params[:deal])

   -#   <------I Need this commented out IF statement back ------->

   -#if @deal.valid? && @organization.deals << @deal

   flash[:notice] = 'Your promotion is published! You may find it in the number 1 position of our #{deal.count} previously posted promotions. To see your promotion, click http://www.website.com>here."'

   respond_to do |format|

   format.html { redirect_to organization_deals_path(@organization) }

   format.js

   -# I Need this IF Statement Back!

   -#else

   -#@disclaimers = Disclaimer.all

   -#render :action => 'new'
   end
   end

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer :

```
@deal_count = Deal.count

flash[:notice] = "blah blah blah #{@deal_count}"
```

I had single quotes around the flash notice. That's what was breaking this.

Second answer :

Yah for some reason this works now. I don't know what I did.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- You do not seem to be setting `@organization` before trying to use that in your `if` condition
- If you want the total number of Deals this is called on the class i.e. `Deal.count` rather than `deal.count`
- Even though you mention adding an extra `end` when uncommenting the `if` it looks like you are missing an `end` in the right place for your `respond_to` block

Comment: No, there are two ends at the end. And I would add a third for the respond_to. I don't think there's any need for more than three in this block.

Comment: Yes, but you need to end the `respond_to` block before the `else` - otherwise the `if` is outside the block but the `else` is inside it.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha. Great point. The #{Deal.count} doesn't work. What do you think that is?